# Jwplayer force Safari browser to play in HTML5 mode

Tags: html, flash, safari, settings, jwplayer

I am using JWplayer 6.
I need to force it to use HTML5 even if HTML5 is **not** supported (this is for RESTing purposes).

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.
I have tried setting `jwplayer("playername").settings({primary: "flash"})` - it didn't work.

Right now I am resorting to disabling flash in browsers but not all browsers/devices allow this without addons.

I am using `(player).getRenderingMode` to determine the playback type so I am absolutely certain that only flash is being played.

Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**:

I have the primary: `"flash"/"HTML5"` setting working in every browser except Safari.
According to `W3C schools` Safari **DOES** support mp4 files in HTML5 mode.

So my question is now how to force Safari to play in HTML5 mode

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Comment: Yes
This one is supposed to play in flash mode
http://www.streaming.co.uk/sam/JWplayer_prototype/Captions_Flash_srt.htm

This one is supposed to work in html5 mode (it does not do this in safari)
http://www.streaming.co.uk/sam/JWplayer_prototype/Captions_html5_srt.htm

Comment: Why is the player set up after the closing </body> tag?

Comment: I always set-up my javascripts after the main body of the document.
I usually use stick the whole lot in a onload event but forgot on this occasion

Comment: Can you put it inside to see if that changes anything?

Comment: Since my last post I have enclosed all the setup code in a document.ready event - I have done this on the pages which are supposed to play in html5 only

Comment: I have moved the script to the body tag - both at the end of it (after the player div) and start of it (before the player div)

nether of these made any difference

Comment: I just checked this link (http://www.streaming.co.uk/sam/JWplayer_prototype/Captions_html5_srt.htm) in Safari 7 on OS X Mavericks and it is rendering in HTML5 mode, not Flash.

Comment: Well on my windows machine it renders in flash
It has the flash right click menu
and it reads flash bellow the video using jwplayer(player).getrendermode()

Comment: I checked Safari on Windows and it is in HTML5 mode for me. Keep in mind Safari on Windows needs QuickTime to be installed to support HTML5 videos.

Comment: I'm having this same issue on Firefox 34 on Yosemite. It is forcing it to flash though primary is set to HTML5.

Comment: I tried the way Ethan JWPlayer explained in 1st comment, and it worked for me. But can you tell me that how do I identify that it is really a HTML5 player?